# iOS5: Has somebody managed to fix UIAlertView with three buttons and textfield (UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput)?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, xamarin.ios, uialertview

Apple really screwed this one up. I want to use a `UIAlertView` with the new `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` style and have three buttons in it. The result looks as follows:

[image]

Has somebody managed to build a workaround until Apple will have fixed this issue? Maybe reducing the button height somehow or increase the total height of the alert view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you format more than two buttons inside an UIAlertView with the UIAlertStylePlainTextInput style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754777/how-do-you-format-more-than-two-buttons-inside-an-uialertview-with-the-uialertst)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but it may get you started.

```
UIAlertView view = new UIAlertView ("Alert", "This is an alert\n\n\n", null, "Login", "One", "Two");

UIView theTextField = new UIView (new RectangleF (12.0f, 80.0f, 260.0f, 25.0f));
UITextView txt = new UITextView (new RectangleF (0f, 0f, 260.0f, 25.0f));
txt.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
theTextField.AddSubview (txt);
view.AddSubview (theTextField); 

view.Show ();
```

I observed that the AlertView tries to be intelligent when you add a text view as a sub view.  But if you put a generic UIView in as a container it gives you something more useable.

I also verified that this is a problem in XCode.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551530/customizing-uialertview) may give you some more ideas.

Comment: But your Solution isnt making use of the new styles at all.

Comment: Nevertheless I tried it now. Brilliant. Works like charm! Thanks!