# Password protect iPhone app

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, password-protection, uiactionsheet

I'm starting a new app, and I'd like to know how to require a password to open it.

I was considering a `UIActionSheet` in the application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of the app delegate implementation file, but am unsure how to go about doing so. I'm going to keep trying though.

Found [this video](http://d2bhmtpcpvp7li.cloudfront.net/HelloWorld-UIActionSheet-001/HelloWorld-UIActionSheet-001-002.mov), which seems pretty helpeful.

Now I've got my `UIActionSheet` to pop up displaying "Enter password," and am trying to figure how to add a keypad to the action sheet.

Comment: I thought something that would help people with the same problem should go in community wiki. Am I mistaken? I apologize if so.

Comment: You should ask for a mod to delete this and make another question without community wiki.

Comment: This answer is also pretty useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/13563490/1359306

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may have better luck using a full `UIViewController` instance instead of a `UIActionSheet`.  Adding keyboard behavior to an action sheet will be difficult if not impossible.

If you create a `UIViewController` subclass, you can make your application delegate present it in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  Assuming you're using some sort of `UIViewController` or `UINaviagtionController` for your main interface, you could have the password view controller presented modally at startup using `UIViewController`-`presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Once you have your password view controller, you'll need to add a `UITextField` for password entry.  Make the text field become `firstResponder` (by calling `becomeFirstResponder` on it), and that will cause the keyboard to be displayed.  You may also want to set the `keyboardAppearance` property on the text field to control how the keypad appears if for example you want to limit to a numeric PIN versus a full password.  Setting the `secureTextEntry` property may also be desirable to prevent the actual password from being display.  See the `UITextInputTraits` protocol on `UITextField` for both of those options.

In order to make the app secure, you would create your password view controller so that it has no buttons or navigation options other than a "Submit" or "Login" type button.  If the user enters the correct password, you dismiss the modal view controller and let them in.  If they don't know the password, their only choice is to tap the Home button to exit your application as they'd have no way to proceed beyond the modal view controller.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense reading it. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet though. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Implementing [UIKeyInput Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) would also be a good idea so you can zeroize the password from the underlying data store. Zeroization is usually required by bodies NIST, DoD (STIGs), CIS (Security Benchmarks), etc.

Comment: @surlac Couple of options.  For maximum security, store it in the app's Keychain.  For reasonable security, store a hash of it in the app's NSUserDefaults and compare the hash of what they enter to what you have stored.  Then there's no way to recover their actual PIN, but you can still verify it.  Google about a bit, and you can find SHA1 hash implementations for iOS that use the built in CommonCrypto libraries.

Answer (score 14):

- https://github.com/guicocoa/pinview
- https://github.com/jasarien/JSLockScreen
- https://github.com/lashad/PTPasscodeViewController
- https://github.com/Koolistov/Passcode

Here are some samples I found.

Note: https://

Answer (score 3):

Thought the repo http://github.com/lashad/PTPasscodeViewController could be useful for someone visit this page.

Answer (score 1):

What about a `UIAlertView`? But I don't know if the app gets rejected or not. A few say yes, the other no. Doesn't know if things changed in the past.

Here are some links:

http://junecloud.com/journal/code/displaying-a-password-or-text-entry-prompt-on-the-iphone.html

[UITextField in UIAlertView on iPhone - how to make it responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376104/uitextfield-in-uialertview-on-iphone-how-to-make-it-responsive)

http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2009/12/username-and-password-uitextfields-in.html

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1674641&start=15&tstart=0

http://icodeblog.com/2009/11/09/iphone-coding-tutorial-inserting-a-uitextfield-in-a-uialertview/

Most of the links do the same, they all use `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`. Someone stated that this isn't needed for iOS 4. And sometimes there are problems. Didn't tried it out, because I don't want to get rejected ...

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had much time to work on this app any more, but when I pick it back up I'll be sure to check out your advice. Thanks!