# Loading up a popup window on first launch, instead of UIAlertView in iOS

Tags: ios, popup, modalviewcontroller

Following on from the question here, [How to create a modal view , for application launch in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961794/how-to-create-a-modal-view-for-application-launch-in-ios)

I want to load up this popup window, code here, https://github.com/icanzilb/MTPopupWindow instead of the UIAlertView.

Could someone explain to me how this could be done?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: I don't get it.. there is code on the github page. Didn't that work?

Comment: Hi Marc,

The code on github works fine but I do not want a UIAlertView to show when the app is launched I want to show the MTPopupWindow but I am unsure about how to do this.

   if (firstTime.length==0) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"hi" message:@"You have open this app first time" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [self firstTime];
}
This is the bit where it calls the UIAlertView, I need to know how to change this to load up the MTPopupWindow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Download the github project
- Drag and drop the `MTPopupWindow` class (.h and .m file) into your project
- Make sure to really copy (and not reference) them (there is some checkbox you have to enable)
- This popup relies on QuartzCore, make sure you added that framework to your project
- Create the info.html file with the content you want to display
- Should be in the same folder as your other source code
- In your view controller add `#import "MTPopupWindow.h"` somewhere in the beginning
- Replace the following code

  ```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"hi" 
                                                  message:@"You have open this app first time"                                                  delegate:self 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" 
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  ```

  With this code

  ```
  [MTPopupWindow showWindowWithHTMLFile:@"info.html" insideView:self.view];
  ```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the answer! But I have this error.

I added the first launch code into the appdelegate.m btw.

"property view controller not found on object of type appdelegate" < error I get

Comment: Maybe remove the `insideView:self.view` part