# Present the previously active ViewController from the Login ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, authentication

I have 4 view controllers: loginVC -> homeVC -> aVC -> **bVC**.

Let's assume the user is currently at **bVC** view controller and decided to switch to another app. When the user switch back to my app, I want to present the loginVC to authenticate the user. Once authenticated, the previous **bVC** view controller is to be presented to the user to continue whatever he/she was doing. I'm not using Navigation Controller in my project.

In `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method, I was able to present the loginVC view controller, but once the user is authenticated, what do I do present the **bVC** view controller? I assume **bVC** is still on the stack when the app resign from active?

```
// AppDelegate.m
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive: (UIApplication*) application {

    NSString *storyboardId = @"LoginIdentifier";
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];  
}

// loginVC.m
-(void)authenticateSuccessful {
    // This doesn't do anything... as I want to present bVC
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: From your loginVC perform a segue if it is not necessary to be on the stack you described or perform programmatically the navigation to the ViewController you want to present.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. How do I know which view controller the user was on before switching to another app? The user could either be on homeVC, aVC, or bVC.

Comment: An easy way would be to save an identifier in NSUserDefaults. Every time viewDidAppear() is called you could update that identifier. From within your loginVC you just have to check now the current stored identifier and perform your logic

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. So any work the user was previously doing in bVC would be lost when I re-present it.

Comment: It depends on your logic. You could save the made changes as well. But it's just one possibility to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Instantiate and show your LoginVC as modal one

2 Dismiss it when a user is authenticated

```
//AppDelegate.m
- (UIViewController *)visibleViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    if (rootViewController.presentedViewController == nil)
    {
        return rootViewController;
    }
    if ([rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:   [UINavigationController class]])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController =    (UINavigationController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        UIViewController *lastViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];

        return [self visibleViewController:lastViewController];
    }
    if ([rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
    {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        UIViewController *selectedViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;

        return [self visibleViewController:selectedViewController];
     }

     UIViewController *presentedViewController = (UIViewController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;

     return [self visibleViewController:presentedViewController];
}

-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive: (UIApplication*) application {
    NSString *storyboardId = @"LoginIdentifier";
    UIViewController *lvc = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
    // I.e show it modally instead of putting to rootViewController
    UIViewController *visibleVC = [self visibleViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
    [visibleVC presentViewController:lvc animated:NO completion:NULL];
}

// loginVC.m
-(void)authenticateSuccessful {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:lvc animated:NO completion:NULL]; will not present the login view controller. Only after setting the following did it present the login view controller   self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];

Comment: Spot on. This is clean and works like a charm. Thank you very much for your help Ilnar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is to **present (or Modal)** a temporary viewController over the current View controller (which is bVC in this case) when the application becomes active.

When a viewcontroller is presented, the object or your bVC is not destroyed and hence you could simply **dismiss** the loginView once the user is authenticated.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(yourMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Adding a notification like this could be helpful if you need to present a LoginView from any requiredView Controller

Please refer the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) on PresentingView controllers

Comment: My project is quite large, it has at least 40 view controllers. All 40 view controllers will have to be an observer of UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification? That's quite a bit of work and I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Give a look into this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516481/xcode-display-login-view-in-applicationdidbecomeactive

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by presenting your loginViewController as a modal one, as said before, but I think that this 'feature' will make your users to go away of your app, because they want the login part done once in their user's life (at their first use of your app).

If you really need the user to be logged in your app (or server) every time he comes back to your app, I advise you to chose to store the user's login informations in an NSUserDefaults.

Keep in mind that the user wants things to be done as seamlessly as possible, they really don't want to type their login/password every time they just go back to your app :)