# IOS & objective C development - how to make the login page appear to the user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I am in my first days of IOS app development, I am trying to build an authentication system for an already existent iOS App using Objective C.

The app's rootviewcontroller is a tabsview followed by navigationControllers.

What i've done so far:

**1- creating the loginviewController class & designing it's UI in the storyboard**

**2- the same thing for the "registration" & "recover my password" classes**

**3- linking the root viewcontroller with the login page with a segue of type modal.**

**4- linking the login page with the registration & recover my password pages with segues of type push.**

Now i don't know the steps that i should follow to make the login page appear to the user when he first enters the app & eventually store his state so he can access the app later without having to enter his credentials every time (unless he logs out).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

I am available for any clarifications or eventually some screenshots/source code  if needed.

**Edit 1** : this is the content of my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in my appdelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    TabsViewController *controller = (TabsViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;


    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    _observer = [[MyStoreObserver alloc] init];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:_observer];

    //Create sub directories in doesn'n exist
    NSString *documentsDirectory =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *pathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"export"];
    BOOL isDir = YES;
    BOOL isFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToFile isDirectory:&isDir];

    if(isFile)
    {
        //it is a file, process it here how ever you like, check isDir to see if its a directory
    }
    else
    {
        [self createSubDirectories];
        //not a file, this is an error, handle it!
    }


    return YES;
}
```

What should I add/change ??

Comment: Hi, look to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767899/present-the-previously-active-viewcontroller-from-the-login-viewcontroller/29768291#29768291

Comment: you created Login view and you want to navigate another view?

Comment: hello llnar , i checked your answer, but i can't seem to find what i should do exactly now, is there some kind of link that should be done between the loginviewController and the rootviewcontroller ? and if there is it's via which methods & what code should i write in these methods?

Comment: @selvadurai  I created the login view , & now what i want is to make it appear to the user when he first enters the application instead of the rootviewcontroller

Comment: @llnar I also noticed that you are using appdelegate.h , is it necessary to use it for my case ?

Comment: are you using story board or xib ?

Comment: @selvadurai i am using storyboards

Comment: check it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202332/xcode-ios-check-if-user-is-logged-in-and-show-different-views-if-not

Comment: @dhaval : I checked it, i noticed that you suggested using keychain to store passwords, it will be a good start for me in the begining just for test purposes , but after that i am definitely going to be using core data because the app already uses it so i have no choice in that.

Comment: @samouray it's depend on u , i think so ,u want user-default or  core-data ?

Comment: @dhaval : i think i will definitely use core data , but i will start testing using user defaults, so if you can help me know exactly what to do after these steps that i mentionned in the question that will be great (using user defaults )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it,

I actually changed the rootviewcontroller  by adding this line of code in appdelegate

```
LoginViewController *controller = (LoginViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

I also changed the entry of the application in my storyboard to be  loginviewcontroller.

And I also added a method called `prepareforSegue` in my `loginviewcontroller`  to pass as a parameter the managed objectcontext because it caused some errors in the beginning:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toHome"]) {
        TabsViewController_iPhone *tabsViewController;
        tabsViewController=[segue destinationViewController];
        tabsViewController.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;

    }

}
```

Hope to have helped someone out there. If you need more explanations on how I fixed the problem I am available. Thank's for everyone.

**Edit:**

After taking some time to understand how objective C works, I came to the conclusion that my answer above was not complete, so this is actually what happend:

After the user logs in the first time, I store his user & password in `NSUserDefaults`. 
When he logs out I set the `NSUserDefaults` user/pass variables to Null.

So now I added a test to the AppdDelegate' `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method that says:

if the user/pass variables on `NSUserDefaults` are set -> go to the main menu screen of the app

else -> go to the login screen of the app.

this is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *username = [defaults stringForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *password = [defaults stringForKey:@"password"];

    if (username != nil && password != nil)
        {

            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            // determine the initial view controller here and instantiate it with
            UIViewController *viewController =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HEQMainMenuView"];

            self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }
    else
        {

            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            // determine the initial view controller here and instantiate it with
            UIViewController *viewController =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HEQLoginView"];

            self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
            //viewController.man
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }
}
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 4):

Set your rootViewController programmatically by checking login status.

You can save your login status as a bool in NSUserDefault after Login & Logout.

After Login

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"LoginStatus"];
```

After Logout

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"LoginStatus"];
```

Modify your appDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: delegate method as follows

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_NAME bundle:nil];

    //Check Login status
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LoginStatus"])
    {
      // user not logged in
      LOGIN_VIEWCONTROLLER *rootviewcontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:LOGIN_VIEWCONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER];
   }
   else
   {
      // user already logged in
      TABBARCONTROLLER *rootviewcontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:TABBARCONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER];
   }
   self.window.rootViewController = rootviewcontroller;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your answer, it made thing a little bit clearer to me right now,  i will try this & eventually post any updates

Answer (score 1):

Two Options:

1) You will need database (core data) to keep track of users log. It also may help you for offline login. You can create and set property 'isLoggedIn' to find last logged in user.

2) Create and save logged-in user details in file. Refer this file for next start up. If user is logged-out , then delete that file.

Update 1:
 Create login View, push tabBar on succesful login , followed by navigation controller for further flow. Refer image : [image: storyboard]

Comment: i prefer the first option, as the app already uses the core data framework, but the thing i need to understand is what method should i use to make the connection between my rootview & the login page & how to implement the core data into that ??

Comment: In ViewDidLoad method of login page check for database for last user login and jump to tabBar on viewWillAppear function. (as it is in-appropriate way to jump to another view before it is loaded.)

Comment: actually i have a different layout for my storyboard so , i don't know if it will affect what you said or not , i will add a screenshot of my storyboard into the question. 

edit: i can't post images because i don't have enough reputation but here is a link to it http://i.stack.imgur.com/5bO1d.png