# UIPicker with UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

I made a research and all posts here are very blury regarding this issue.
I would like to use a UIPicker when pressing on a UITextField.
I would realy appriciate a step by step guide.

I tryd all posts here but every post gives me only a portion of what I need and I can't seem to connect it all together.

This is the last part of my application and i'm going crazy to finish it..

Thank you in advanced!

Gal

Comment: Can you really press UITextfield ?
And what you want from picker,what should be done?

Comment: I created a handy subclass of UITextField, PickerTextField: https://github.com/CullenSUN/PickerTextField. That might help someone looking for similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an **inputAccessoryView** property that contains a view that will appear instead of a keyboard on the bottom of the screen. Create a UIPicker, adjust its frame, provide values and assign it to the inputAccessoryView property.

UIPicker will appear when user taps on your UITextField.

If you don't need editing, you may use a UILabel instead of the UITextField. Solution is the same. I have a ready-made class if you need.

Comment: Also a good solution. Found something relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974131/xcode-displaying-a-uidatepicker-when-user-clicks-on-uitextbox

Comment: Actually I used it for a date picker, can't seem to get it work on a UIPicker.. Tnx anyway..

Comment: What's the problem with UIPicker?

Comment: I meant is there any error messages or something? What do you see? Does the UIPicker appears correctly on screen if you add it as a subview, not an inputaccessory?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_F1ex5opgA&t=14m10s

```
-(BOOL)textfieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

- where `textField` is the name of your text field.

Call your UIPickerView and return NO so that your picker is loaded rather than the keyboard.

Comment: I tryd it, I have 3 UITextField. 1 is regular keyboard. 2 I want it to be a UIPikcer. 3 is a UIDatePicker (works with the solution you posted..

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to call an action that opens the UIPicker when the user taps the UITextField. Because the UITextField does not responde to the usual touchUpInside events that UIButtons respond to, I would just overlay a transparent UIButton on top of the UITextField and just in case, make the text field's userInteractionEnabled property NO. Hook the UIButton to responde to touchUpInside and call a method that opens the UIPicker. Another option would be an immediate response to the text field's touch by implementing "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" and immediately resigning the text field.

The next step would be to present the UIPicker - if we are talking about iPad, this would best be done by using a UIPopoverController. On iPhone, maybe consider bringing it up modally. When you create the view controller that holds this UIPicker, be sure to add a delegate property to it so that whatever value that was selected on the picker can be transfered back to the main view controller and on to the UITextField.

Hope this helps with getting you started.

Comment: Hey Stav, how can I contact you in private?