# UIAlertView + TextField = NSString

Tags: iphone

If I had a correctly placed UITextField on an UIAlertView, could I assign the TextField's text value inside NSString using:

```
NSString *string = myTextField.text
```

And what is the method for doing that when the UIAlertView's Button is pressed? (all of my code is on the`-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching`method.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that if you subclassed uiAlertview and hold a reference to your textfield.
That way your string will contain the text entered in the textview.

The method for doing that would be do subclass UIAlertview to hold a uitext view. 
Putting all code in `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching` is not good design.

[This will help you](http://tinyurl.com/3zcfs4u).

Comment: How to hold a reference to the TextField?

Comment: Check the results in the link i have pasted. There are many projects on github which have subclassed uialertview to hold a uitext view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376104/uitextfield-in-uialertview-on-iphone-how-to-make-it-responsive - Anyways check this question and read Stackoverflow FAQ.